# Reading matlab data structure into numpy arrays

Tags: matlab, numpy-ndarray, hdf5, h5py

I have a set of MAT-files which contains a **matlab** `struct`. The struct has bunch of arrays. I would like to open the file and transfer all of them into arrays. So far I have written the following code:

```
import h5py
>>> fs = h5py.File('statistics_VAD.mat','r')
>>> list(fs.keys())
['#refs#', 'data']
>>> 
>>> fs['data'].visititems(lambda n,o:print(n, o))
C <HDF5 dataset "C": shape (100, 1), type "|O">
P <HDF5 dataset "P": shape (100, 1), type "|O">
V <HDF5 dataset "V": shape (100, 1), type "|O">
Wn <HDF5 dataset "Wn": shape (100, 1), type "|O">
X <HDF5 dataset "X": shape (100, 1), type "|O">
a <HDF5 dataset "a": shape (100, 1), type "|O">
dn <HDF5 dataset "dn": shape (100, 1), type "|O">
>>> struArray = fs['data']
>>> print(struArray['P'])
<HDF5 dataset "P": shape (100, 1), type "|O">
```

I don't know how to transfer `HDF5 dataset "P"` to a `numpy` array.  Any suggestion would be appreciated

Comment: What does `arr=struArray['P'][:]` do?

Comment: @hpaulj  the output is `>>> arr=struArray['P'][:]
>>> arr
array([[<HDF5 object reference>],
       [<HDF5 object reference>],
       [<HDF5 object reference>],
       [<HDF5 object reference>],
       [<HDF5 object reference>],
       [<HDF5 object reference>],
       ...`.

Comment: Those 'object refs' probably are items in the `refs` group, but I don't know if `h5py` can fetch them for you.    `scipy.io.loadmat` can handle older style .mat file, but even there the result can have 'opaque' elements.  Not everything that matlab saves to a file is translatable into numpy.

Comment: @hpaulj since I used this command line in matlab to save data `save( 'statistics_VAD.mat','data', '-v7.3');` I get this error using `scipy.io.loadmat`: `mat_contents = sio.loadmat(mat_fname)
    raise NotImplementedError('Please use HDF reader for matlab v7.3 files')
NotImplementedError: Please use HDF reader for matlab v7.3 files`

Comment: I wasn't recommending you use that reader.

Comment: @hpaulj are you saying it is better I go back to matlab to analyze the data? :)

Comment: I have no idea what's in your MATLAB struct.  `loadmat` can handle files written in the pre 7.3 style provided they just contain struct and cells with plain matrix elements, though the result may be a complicated layering of structured and object dtype arrays.  Other SO have explored 7.3 files with varying degrees of success.

Comment: @hpaulj all the elements in my Matlab struct are arrays. Can you suggest other SO in python which would let me to explore and use the data saved in matlab?

Comment: No.  You get to do your own search!  But be careful with some of the older posts.  MATLAB appears to have changed its `HDF5` format one or more times.  I only have Octave to experiment with, and I don't know if it's kept up with MATLAB's changes in this area.

Comment: @Dalek,working with Matlab data saved as HDF5 can be a headache, mostly because Matlab uses tons of object references, and  you have to figure out the schema on your own. I read thru the comments, and you're on the right track. So far we know `fs['data']['P']` is an array of object references of shape (100,1). An object can be used to reference another object in the file, or to hold an nested array -- an array of arrays. What do you get if you `print (struArray['P'][1,1])`? Knowing this might help deduce the schema.

Comment: @kcw78 I get this output for your suggestion `ValueError: Index (1) out of range (0-0)` but with this command I got `>>> print (struArray['P'][1])
[<HDF5 object reference>]` .

Comment: Use `[0,0]` to get the first element. The shape is (100,1)

Comment: @hpaulj It returns again similar result `>>> print (struArray['P'][0,0])  
<HDF5 object reference>`.

Comment: @Dalek sorry about the indexing error -- I wasn't paying attention. To get the referenced object, you use it with your file object (similar to group/dataset names). So, for this object: `struArray['P'][0,0]` the referenced object is `fs [  struArray['P'][0,0] ]`. To demonstrate behavior I put a little example together and posted as an "answer". (It's not an exact answer, but shows the process to use to get the objects, then read the dereferenced data. I also added code for a region reference (for completeness).

Answer (score 1):

Code below is the example mentioned in my comment (dtd 2021-03-01). It creates 2 datasets from NumPy arrays, then a dataset with 2 object references, 1 to each dataset. It then shows how to use the object references to access the data. A second dataset with region references is also done for completeness.

Notice how `h5f[]` is used twice: the inner one gets the object, and the outer one gets the data from the object reference. It's a subtlety that trips users new to references.

```
import numpy as np
import h5py

with h5py.File('SO_66410592.h5','w') as h5f :
    # Create 2 datasets using numpy arrays
    arr = np.arange(100).reshape(20,5)
    h5f.create_dataset('array1',data=arr)    
    arr = np.arange(100,0,-1).reshape(20,5)
    h5f.create_dataset('array2',data=arr) 
    
    # Create a dataset of OBJECT references: 
    h5f.create_dataset('O_refs', (10,), dtype=h5py.ref_dtype)
    h5f['O_refs'][0] = h5f['array1'].ref
    print (h5f['O_refs'][0])
    print (h5f[ h5f['O_refs'][0] ])
    print (h5f[ h5f['O_refs'][0] ][0,:])
    h5f['O_refs'][1] = h5f['array2'].ref
    print (h5f['O_refs'][1])
    print (h5f[ h5f['O_refs'][1] ])
    print (h5f[ h5f['O_refs'][1] ][-1,:])

    # Create a dataset of REGION references: 
    h5f.create_dataset('R_refs', (10,), dtype=h5py.regionref_dtype)
    h5f['R_refs'][0] = h5f['array1'].regionref[0,:]
    print (h5f['R_refs'][0])
    print (h5f[ h5f['R_refs'][0] ])    
    print (h5f[ h5f['R_refs'][0] ] [ h5f['R_refs'][0] ]) 
    h5f['R_refs'][1] = h5f['array2'].regionref[-1,:]
    print (h5f['R_refs'][1])
    print (h5f[ h5f['R_refs'][1] ])    
    print (h5f[ h5f['R_refs'][1] ] [ h5f['R_refs'][1] ])
```